# Aplicacion javafx se cuelga inciar en el arranque

Tags: javafx, java-8, raspberry-pi, raspbian

he venido acá porque ya tengo meses con este problema y he buscado en todas partes pero no consigo solución. 
Tengo una aplicación realizada en javafx para una raspberry pi 4 b+ con raspbian Streatch y con java 8 222. El programa es una especie de juego de mesa tiene varias animaciones que se repiten, el punto es que luego de usarlo por unas 3 horas el juego se cuelga y solo actualiza las cosas mas pequeñas de la GUI (por ejemplo una imagen de un avatar que tiene que cambiar, o los puntos) pero el resto queda congelado. Logre resolver el problema aplicando una serie de flags u opciones para que la GPU se comporte de manera de diferente. Lo extraño es que cuando corro el programa con esas opciones manualmente todo funciona bien pero cuando lo hago por el script de inicio automático persiste el problema. Actualmente el script lo invoco en el archivo /etc/rc.local

No tengo idea de que puede estar pasando ojala me puedan ayudar, les dejo las opciones con las que estoy iniciando java, muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda:

```
sudo java -Dpi4j.linking=dynamic -Dprism.verbose=true -Dprism.debug=true -Dprism.order=es2 -Dprism.dirtyopts=false -Dprism.cacheshapes=simple -Dprism.allowhidpi=false -Dprism.disableRegionCaching -Dprism.disableEffects=true -Dprism.disableD3D9Ex=true -Dprism.supershader=false -Dprism.forceNonAntialiasedShape=true -Xmx212m -jar /root/bolirana/Boli_0.1.jar
```